# ¿Cómo hacer un select list con Rails mediante collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Buenas comunidad, estoy trantando de hacer un select list en Rails con Boostrap utilizando la gema simple for form pero me da error.

Comment: ¿Qué error te muestra?, ¿cuál es el código que estás utilizando?

Comment: Hola Gerry! El error era que estaba utilizando f.input en vez de f.collection_select. Gracias! Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi y le agregas la clase de bootstrap asi lo uso yo te dejo un ejemplo

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
 <%= f.collection_select :vendor_id, Model.all, :id, :vendor, :include_blank => true, class: "class-bootstrap" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```